# Send data from Broadcast receiver to MainActivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, send

I need to display status of connection on the screen. It seemed a simple task...

This is my receiver code below:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public PowerConnectionReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
        state = "Charging";
        Toast.makeText(context, state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        state = "Not charging";
        Toast.makeText(context, state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

How can i display my STATE var on screen textView. Can anybody help with it? Thanks!

Comment: what problem you are facing right now?

Comment: any errors with your posted code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a `Callback`. Create an `Interface` in `PowerConnectionReceiver` like:

```
public Interface NetworkStatusCallback {
    public void onStateChange(String state);
}
```

Now implement this `Callback` in your `MainActivity` like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PowerConnectionReceiver.NetworkStatusCallback  {...}
```

Create a `reference` of this `Callback` in  `PowerConnectionReceiver` and declare it like:

```
private NetworkStatusCallback mCallback;
mCallBack = (NetworkStatusCallback)context;
```

Now in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` do this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
        state = "Charging";
        mCallback.onStateChange(state);
        Toast.makeText(context, state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        state = "Not charging";
        mCallback.onStateChange(state);
        Toast.makeText(context, state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You will receive state in `MainActivity`

Comment: thaks a lot,  tell me please how to receive it, in onCreate or make onReceive method?

Comment: when you will implement that callback in MainActivity, you will also implement its function onStateChange(state); . This is where you will receive it.

Comment: @БорисБойко May I know the reason for unaccepting this answer?

Comment: don't worry i just find better solution for me

Comment: @БорисБойко ok no problem. Thanks :)